# JSLint unused variable error

Tags: javascript, variables, validation, jslint

I created a javascript document and I want to make this JSlint valid.

http://pastebin.com/GvZLyNbV

```
/*jslint browser: true, indent: 2 */
/*global ActiveXObject: true, window: true*/
(function (window) {
  "use strict";
  /**
   * ajax class
   * 
   * ez az objektum fogja kezelni az ajax kérelmeket. lényege hogy nagyon 
   * minimális legyen. nem akarom jobban magyarázni, eléggé bonyolult, mert a
   * különböző böngészők különbözően kezelik az ajax hívásokat.
   */
  var ajax = window.ajax = {};

  ajax.XHR = {
    getXHR: function () {
      var http;
      try {
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        this.getXHR = function () {
          return new XMLHttpRequest();
        };
        return http;
      } catch (e) { }

      try {
        http = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
        this.getXHR = function () {
          return new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0");
        };
        return http;
      } catch (f) { }

      try {
        http = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
        this.getXHR = function () {
          return new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
        };
        return http;
      } catch (g) { }

      try {
        http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        this.getXHR = function () {
          return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        };
        return http;
      } catch (h) { }
    },

    call: function (method, uri, callback, postData) {
      var xhr = this.getXHR();

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
          if (typeof callback === "function") {
            callback(xhr);
          }
        }
      };

      xhr.open(method, uri, true);

      if (method === "POST") {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        //xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postData.length);
        //xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        xhr.send(postData);
      } else {
        xhr.send(null);
      }
      return xhr;
    }
  };



  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /**
   * periodic object
   * 
   * Ez az osztály kezeli a periodikus hívások egyesítését. Hozzá tudunk adni 
   * listenereket
   * @see ajax.ListenerObj
   * 
   * Az a lényege hogy az összes listenert átnézi és egyesíti a requesteket
   * így egy kérelemben egybe elküldi az összes requestet.
   * 
   * @todo Jobban kellene rendezni az osztályt, ne csak így a levegőben lógjon,
   * meg majd bele kell venni a benchmark osztályt is meg jobban kell időzíteni.
   * 
   */

  ajax.periodic = {};


  ajax.periodic.isListen = false;
  ajax.periodic.timer = null;
  ajax.periodic.listenDelay = 5000;
  ajax.periodic.url = "ajax.php";
  ajax.periodic.listeners = [];

  /**
   * Ezzel a függvénnyel indítjuk el a periodikus hívásokat
   */
  ajax.periodic.startListen = function () {
    window.clearTimeout(ajax.periodic.timer);
    ajax.periodic.isListen = true;
    ajax.periodic.listen();
  };

  /**
   * Ezzel a fügvénnyel állítjuk le a periodikus hívásokat 
   */
  ajax.periodic.stopListen = function () {
    window.clearTimeout(ajax.periodic.timer);
    ajax.periodic.isListen = false;
  };

  /**
   * Ezzel a fügvénnyel adhatunk új ListenerObj objektumot a periodic osztályhoz
   * 
   * @see ajax.ListenerObj
   */
  ajax.periodic.addListener = function (obj) {
    if (obj instanceof ajax.ListenerObj) {
      ajax.periodic.listeners.push(obj);
    }
  };

  /**
   * Ezzel a fügvénnyel törölhetünk egy ListenerObj objektumot a periodic
   * osztályból
   * 
   * @see ajax.ListenerObj 
   */
  ajax.periodic.removeListener = function (obj) {
    var i = ajax.periodic.listeners.indexOf(obj);
    if (i >= 0) {
      ajax.periodic.listeners.splice(i, 1);
    }
  };

  /**
   * Ezzel a fügvénnyel kérdezzük le az össze ListenerObj objektum paramját
   * 
   * @param method : Ez "GET" vagy "POST" lehet
   * @param escape : Ez az hogy encodolja-e a tartalmat (default true)
   */
  ajax.periodic.getListenersQueries = function (method, escape) {
    var allQueries = new ajax.QueryCollection(),
      i;
    escape = (escape === false) ? false : true;
    for (i = 0; i < ajax.periodic.listeners.length; i += 1) {
      if (ajax.periodic.listeners[i].isListen()) {
        allQueries.mergeCollection(ajax.periodic.listeners[i].queries);
      }
    }

    return allQueries.queriesToString(method, escape);
  };

  /**
   * Ez a függvény meghíváskor elindul, és periodicc.delay időközönként
   * újrahívja magát. Az AJAX válaszban kapott adatot továbbítja a ListenerObj
   * objektumoknak.
   */
  ajax.periodic.listen = function () {
    if (!ajax.periodic.isListen) {
      return;
    }

    var startTime = (new Date()).getTime(),
      uri = ajax.periodic.url + "?" + ajax.periodic.getListenersQueries("get"),
      postData = ajax.periodic.getListenersQueries("post"),
      i;

    for (i = 0; i < ajax.periodic.listeners.length; i += 1) {
      ajax.periodic.listeners[i].setRequest(true);
    }

    ajax.XHR.call("POST", uri, function (data, status) {
      var i, delay;

      for (i = 0; i < ajax.periodic.listeners.length; i += 1) {
        if (ajax.periodic.listeners[i].isRequest() === true) {
          ajax.periodic.listeners[i].setRequest(false);
          ajax.periodic.listeners[i].parse(data);
        }
      }

      delay = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
      ajax.periodic.timer = window.setTimeout(ajax.periodic.listen, ((delay < ajax.periodic.listenDelay) ? ajax.periodic.listenDelay - delay : 0));
    }, postData);
  };

  /**
   * paraméterben megadott listener egyszer requesteli.
   */
  ajax.periodic.request = function (listener, func) {
    func = (typeof func === "function") ? func : function () {};

    ajax.XHR.call("POST", ajax.periodic.url + "?" + listener.queries.queriesToString("GET"), function (data, status) {
      func(data);
    }, ajax.listener.queries.queriesToString("POST"));
  };





  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  /**
   * ajax.QueryCollection class
   * 
   * Ez az osztály a query paramétereket tárolja el.
   */
  ajax.QueryCollection = function () {
    var queryArray = [];

    this.queryArray = queryArray;


    /**
     * Query paraméter hozzáadása
     */
    this.addQuery = function (method, name, value) {
      if (!method || !name) {
        return this;
      }

      method = method.toString().toLowerCase();
      name = name.toString();
      value = (value === undefined) ? "" : value.toString();

      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < queryArray.length; i += 1) {
        if (queryArray[i].method === method && queryArray[i].name === name) {
          queryArray[i].value = value;
          return;
        }
      }
      //if not found then add a new
      queryArray.push({
        "method": method,
        "name": name,
        "value": value
      });
    };

    /**
     * Query paraméter törlése
     */
    this.removeQuery = function (method, name) {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < queryArray.length; i += 1) {
        if (queryArray[i].method === method && queryArray[i].name === name) {
          queryArray[i].splice(i, 1);
          return;
        }
      }
    };

    /**
     * Két ilyen osztály egyesítése
     */
    this.mergeCollection = function (obj) {
      if (!obj instanceof ajax.QueryCollection) {
        return;
      }
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < obj.queryArray.length; i += 1) {
        this.addQuery(obj.queryArray[i].method, obj.queryArray[i].name, obj.queryArray[i].value);
      }
    };

    /*
     * Az argumentumban található osztály querijainak törlése ebből az osztályból
     */
    this.splitCollection = function (obj) {
      if (!obj instanceof ajax.QueryCollection) {
        return;
      }
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < obj.queryArray.length; i += 1) {
        this.removeQuery(obj.queryArray[i].method, obj.queryArray[i].name);
      }
    };

    /*
     * Queryk egyesítése stringbe
     */
    this.queriesToString = function (method, escape) {
      var str = "",
        cnt = 0,
        i;

      escape = (escape === false) ? false : true;

      for (i = 0; i < queryArray.length; i += 1) {
        if (queryArray[i].method === method) {
          if (cnt !== 0) {
            str += "&";
          }

          cnt += 1;

          str += queryArray[i].name;

          if (queryArray[i].value !== "") {
            str += "=";

            if (escape === true) {
              str += encodeURIComponent(queryArray[i].value);
            }
            else {
              str += queryArray[i].value;
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return str;
    };
  };

  /*
   * ajax.ListenerObj class
   * 
   * Ez az osztály arra való hogy segítségvel csinálhatok listener objektumokat
   * amiknek beállíthatok queriket.
   */
  ajax.ListenerObj = function () {

    var isListen = false,
      isRequest = false,
      parserFunc = function () {};

    this.queries = new ajax.QueryCollection();

    this.setListen = function (a) {
      isListen = (a) ? true : false;
    };
    this.isListen = function () {
      return isListen;
    };

    this.setRequest = function (a) {
      isRequest = (a) ? true : false;
    };

    this.isRequest = function () {
      return isRequest;
    };

    this.setParser = function (a) {
      if (typeof a === "function") {
        parserFunc = a;
      }
      return this;
    };

    this.parse = function (data) {
      parserFunc(data);
    };
  };

}(window));
```

When i validate this with JSLint, I get this error:

```
Error:
Unused variable: status 182 'uri', status 203 'GET'
```

I don't understand what should I fix. The `uri` variable is used, and the `'GET'` is a string constant, not a variable.

So I am totally confused.

Comment: Sites like pastebin can be a useful **adjunct** to your question, but always include the relevant code ***in the question itself***. People trying to help you shouldn't need to click-through to another site, and external links can change / get moved / disappear, which would render your question completely useless for anyone else in the future. Also, in this case, you've linked to a **massive** code sample. You'll need to spend some time zeroing in on the problem.

Comment: my code is 369 lines length. is it really a good practise to include in the question?

Comment: `@omnosis`: A) Yes, and B) Its **better** practice to zero in on the problem rather than expecting people to read through 369 lines of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, starting on line 182, there's a function you pass into `ajax.XHR.call` which declares a variable, `status`, that you never use:

```
//                         |-- Function starts here
//                         V               V-- Variable (argument) `status`, never used
ajax.XHR.call("POST", uri, function (data, status) {
  var i, delay;

  for (i = 0; i < ajax.periodic.listeners.length; i += 1) {
    if (ajax.periodic.listeners[i].isRequest() === true) {
      ajax.periodic.listeners[i].setRequest(false);
      ajax.periodic.listeners[i].parse(data);
    }
  }

  delay = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
  ajax.periodic.timer = window.setTimeout(ajax.periodic.listen, ((delay < ajax.periodic.listenDelay) ? ajax.periodic.listenDelay - delay : 0));
}, postData);
```

You can get rid of the error by removing the argument from the function signature. Or you can ignore it, because it's very important to remember that JSLint is all about Douglas Crockford's *coding style*, which may or may not be what you believe to be appropriate for your own coding style. You might also look at [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/), which gives you more control over options.

Comment: Removing the parameter works in this scenario, but not always. Don't ignore the warning, it raises a great question. Why should I have to name parameters I'm not going to use? Maybe if they linted at jQuery they would have rethought the idea of having so many parameters in their callback signatures, maybe they would have wrapped them up in an object. The ajax.error callback has 3 parameters before the only one I want, 'exception'. I never thought about it before the warning, now I'll think about it for every function I write and I think I'm left a better developer for it.

Comment: @JasonKostempski: Yeah, I would never point to jQuery as a great example of API design. :-) (Nor would I hold out much hope it would have been better if the designers had been using lint tools [which they very well may have been].) But there are pros and cons to almost all design choices, and it's not always obvious which ones to pay attention to. Good point about really thinking about the users of your API when designing it, and kudos for being the kind of engineer who's clearly always trying to improve.

Answer (score 1):

> Unused variable: status 182 'uri', status 203 'GET'

Means that you have unused variable `status` on lines 182 and 203.

Comment: Sorry. But my problem is that I __use__ the `uri`. That's the problem.

Comment: the problem is not in uri or GET, its in "status". your unused variable is "status".

Comment: pff. i just got confused. tryed to found out the problem aboute uri. I dont know why JSLint wrote it.